# VBA ADO error 3709

Tags: vba, excel, ado

i try to connect to an excel DB ( i know it's not the perfect DB but i cannot use access but i must use excel so...)
everything work fine until the line with : objRecordset.Open

i get an error and i admit i have no clue how to solve it

here is the code

```
Sub macromacro()
'On Error Resume Next

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

'***** Creation de la connection *****
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
& "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\StatsLyon.xlsm;" _
    & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"


'***** Requête SQL *****
objRecordset.Open

Query = "Select SUM(NbCompteurElec) AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] ," _
& "objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText"

Feuil5.Cells(1, 3).Value = "NombreTotal"
Feuil5.Cells(1, 4).Value = objRecordset.Fields(NombreTotal).Value

objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ACE with *.xlsm & *.xlsx:

```
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
& "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\StatsLyon.xlsm;" _
    & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
```

You might also like to use

```
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007 for more information.

Then:

```
objRecordset.Open "Select SUM(NbCompteurElec) AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$]", _
objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

Edit re comments

```
sSQL = "Select SUM(NbCompteurElec) AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] " _
     & "WHERE [DateMad] Between #" _
     & Format(date_deb,"yyyy/mm/dd") _
     & "# And #" & Format(date_fin,"yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"

objRecordset.Open sSQL, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

The delimiter for dates is # 
It is always best to format dates to year (yyyy), month, day as it is never ambiguous.

Comment: i have to thank you Remou for the quick answer still not working, same error

Comment: haha very nice, you're a BOSS Remou, i sill have a minor error on     Feuil5.Cells(1, 4).Value = objRecordset.Fields(NombreTotal).Value
but i think i'll get it to work after debugging that last line
anyway i have to thank you Remou, you saved me some hours of debugging :P

Comment: That should be `Fields("NombreTotal").Value`

Comment: It is not my site, I wish it were, connectionstrings is a very famous "old" site.

Comment: Hey Remou, last question, do you know how to use a variable in the sql query for dates?

Comment: nah, i was talking about lessthandot :p
Remou, i want to use variable in my sql query and cannot find the right syntax for it
like:
    date_deb = Feuil2.Cells(1, 1)
    date_fin = Feuil2.Cells(2, 1)
    objRecordset.Open "Select SUM(NbCompteurElec) AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] WHERE [DateMad] Between Format( & date_deb,'mm\/dd\/yyyy') And Format( & date_fin,'mm\/dd\/yyyy');", _
objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic